# Knowing the functional form, how to find best-fit parameters and their uncertainties for a set of raw data in Mathematica 8?

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am trying to plot the best-fit curve (with known functional form but free parameters) passing through the following set of discrete data points which would take into account the size of error bars using Least Squares Fitting Procedure. I would like to find the best parameters along with their uncertainties as follows:

```
Needs["ErrorBarLogPlots`"]
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
h=0.7;
Data = {{{9.6 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.292)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.292)*{10^(-0.063) - 1, 10^0.072 - 1}]}, {{9.7 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.347)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.347)*{10^(-0.029) - 1, 10^0.031 - 1}]}, {{9.8 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.289)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.289)*{10^(-0.028) - 1, 10^0.030 - 1}]}, {{9.9 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.308)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.308)*{10^(-0.036) - 1, 10^0.040 - 1}]}, {{10 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.325)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.325)*{10^(-0.027) - 1, 10^0.028 - 1}]}, {{10.1 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.253)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.253)*{10^(-0.073) - 1, 10^0.087 - 1}]}, {{10.2 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.342)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.342)*{10^(-0.028) - 1, 10^0.030 - 1}]}, {{10.3 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.372)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.372)*{10^(-0.025) - 1, 10^0.027 - 1}]}, {{10.4 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(\[Minus]2.327)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.327)*{10^(-0.033) - 1, 10^0.036 - 1}]}, {{10.5 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.332)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.332)*{10^(-0.028) - 1, 10^0.030 - 1}]}, {{10.6 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.384)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.384)*{10^(-0.026) - 1, 10^0.028 - 1}]}, {{10.7 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.360)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.360)*{10^(-0.031) - 1, 10^0.033 - 1}]}, {{10.8 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.493)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.493)*{10^(-0.028) - 1, 10^0.029 - 1}]}, {{10.9 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.644)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.644)*{10^(-0.036) - 1, 10^0.039 - 1}]}, {{11 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.734)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.734)*{10^(-0.036) - 1, 10^0.039 - 1}]}, {{11.1 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-2.978)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-2.978)*{10^(-0.047) - 1, 10^0.052 - 1}]}, {{11.2 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-3.114)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-3.114)*{10^(-0.057) - 1, 10^0.066 - 1}]}, {{11.3 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-3.46)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-3.46)*{10^(-0.083) - 1, 10^0.10 - 1}]}, {{11.4 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-3.67)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-3.67)*{10^(-0.10) - 1, 10^0.10 - 1}]}, {{11.5 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-4.12)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-4.12)*{10^(-0.20) - 1, 10^0.30 - 1}]}, {{11.6 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-4.35)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-4.35)*{10^(-0.20) - 1, 10^0.40 - 1}]}, {{11.7 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-5.09)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-5.09)*{10^(-0.40) - 1, 10^1.00 - 1}]}, {{11.8 + Log10[h], Log[10]*10^(-5.05)}, ErrorBar[Log[10]*10^(-5.05)*{10^(-0.40) - 1, 10^1.00 - 1}]}};
model = 
  Log[10]*Exp[-10^(x - Log10[h] - a)]*10^b*(10^(x - Log10[h] - a))^(c + 1);
curve = 
 NonlinearModelFit[Data, model, {a,b,c}, x]
```

And, then to plot both raw data and best-fit on the same plot using `Show` command as follows:

```
Show[ErrorListLogPlot[Data, 
  PlotRange -> {{9.25, 11.95}, {5*10^-6, 0.2}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, Joined -> False, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["X", FontSize -> 24], Style["Y", FontSize -> 24]}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 24]], 
  LogPlot[curve[x], {x, 9.25, 11.95}, PlotRange -> {5*10^-6, 0.2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]
However, the second step (plotting) will be possible only once the free parameters and their uncertainties are found. Your help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: `Data` is not a `{x,y}` data. Use `NonlinearModelFit[Data[[All,1]], model, {a, b, c, d, f}, x]`

Comment: Your model does not seem to easily reproduce the trend in your experimental data. You will need to provide much better starting values for your parameters. Also, you can use 1/errors as weights in your fit (see the [`Weights`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Weights.html) option), but not in the format in which you have them for plotting. I'd suggest that you ignore the weigthing issue first, and get some decent starting values (if a, b, c etc have physical meaning, then you should be able to provide some better estimate; if they don't, then simplify your model).

Comment: @Sumit, thank for the clarification. But I am not getting the uncertainties of the central values. Is there any other approach so I can get those?

Comment: @MarcoB, thanks for the feedback. You are right. Now, I have a better model. I edited it.

Comment: Implement @MarcoB 's suggestion of better starting values by replacing `{a,b,c}` with `{{a,10},b,c}`.

Comment: @Benjamin So could you share those better initial values? Then we might be able to help you with the error weighting.

Comment: @MarcoB: {{a, 10.36}, {b, -3.35}, {c, -2.76}} are the best initial values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Step 1 - Find reasonable starting values

Typically one uses `Manipulate` in order to get values that are in the ball park.

Using your `data` and `model` create `measuredData` to be the `{x,y}` pairs extracted from the `data`.

```
h = 0.7;

model = Log[10]*Exp[-10^(x - Log10[h] - a)]*10^b*(10^(x - Log10[h] - a))^(c + 1)

(* 10^b (10^(0.154902 - a + x))^(1 + c) E^-10^(0.154902 - a + x) Log[10] *)

measuredData = data[[All, 1]]
```

Create a `Manipulate` and see if it is possible to locate reasonable starting values.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  LogPlot[
   Log[10]*Exp[-10^(x - Log10[h] - a)]*10^
     b*(10^(x - Log10[h] - a))^(c + 1), {x, 9.4, 11.7}, 
   PlotStyle -> Black],
  ListLogPlot[measuredData, PlotStyle -> Red],
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, All}
  ],

 {{a, 11}, 5, 15, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{b, -2}, -3, 3, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{c, -1}, -3, 3, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Step 2 - NonlinearModelFit with weights

Create the weights assuming that the uncertainty for each data point equals the difference between the positive and negative error divided by the measured value, this quantity squared.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
weights = Map[(measuredData[[#,2]]/(data[[#,2,1,2]] - data[[#,2,1,1]]))^2 &,
               Range[Length@data]]
```

Normalize the weights:

```
weights = Normalize[weights]

(* {0.0531704, 0.27532, 0.294666, 0.170646, 0.328493, \
0.0372979, 0.294666, 0.366696, 0.207596, 0.294666, 0.340004, \
0.241928, 0.305815, 0.175643, 0.175643, 0.100157, 0.0641387, \
0.0282171, 0.0244968, 0.00284079, 0.00149458, 0.0000573521, \
0.0000573521} *)
```

Now run `NonlinearModelFit`.

```
weightedCurve =  NonlinearModelFit[measuredData, model,
     {{a, 11}, {b, -2}, {c, -1}}, x, Weights -> weights]

weightedCurve["BestFitParameters"]

(* {a -> 10.8517, b -> -2.10571, c -> -0.830111} *)

weightedCurve["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am unable to locate the `ErrorBarLogPlots` package. Below is a plot without the error bars.

```
Show[
 LogPlot[weightedCurve[x], {x, 9.4, 11.7}, PlotStyle -> Black],
 ListLogPlot[measuredData, PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, All}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Alternatively: `weights = Normalize[weights, First]`.

Comment: Dear Jack, thanks for this. I am working to see if this will work for me. I am receiving the following error message for Step 1 without any fit drawn: "LogPlot::exclul: {Im[10^(0.154902 -par1+x)]-0,Im[10^(0.154902 -par1+x)]-0}
 must be a list of equalities or real-valued functions. >>"

Comment: For the second method, I am receiving again nonsense answer for the weights command as follows: {72773.9 ErrorBar[{-0.00158728, 0.00211964}]^2, 485450. ErrorBar[{-0.000668975, 0.000766276}]^2...etc and subsequently the next lines are producing lots of error messages. What am I doing incorrectly???

Comment: For the second step, I am entering this line first which doesn't seem to act accordingly: weights =                                          Map[(Data[[#,2]]/(Data[[#, 2, 1, 2]] - Data[[#, 2, 1, 1]]))^2 &, Range[Length@Data]]

Comment: There is a `measuredData` constructed from the `data` that you are missing. `measuredData = data[[All, 1]]`